# Moving rotated squares on top of canvas image

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

I need to be able to draw squares on top of an image in a canvas. I also need to be able to zoom and rotate the image while keeping the aspect ratios of the squares drawn the same and in the same place. If the canvas is rotated I would still like to be able to zoom or move the square without the image reverting to the original position. As it stands right now, I am able to zoom and rotate an image that is drawn on a canvas but when I rotate and then zoom it reverts to the original position. I can also move a square that is drawn on top of the canvas. The square keeps the same aspect ratio when zoomed. The problem I need help with is getting the image to stay rotated when zooming, as well as getting the squares to stay in the same spot when rotating the image while still allowing them to be moved. Right now when I rotate the canvas, the image rotates fine, but the square is drawn in another place and it cannot be moved when clicked.

I am not too familiar with jsFiddle, but I have created [one](http://jsfiddle.net/gblock0/wkMzw/) with all my JS. It doesn't display the image, but in my sample app it does. I am loading the js file after the `<canvas>` but I do not know how to do that in jsFiddle. If you can help me get it to display the image, you should be able to see how it is working right now.

**Thanks in advance!**

***EDIT: Added my JS***

```
var startScale = 1;
var scale = 0.8;
var $docCanvas = $('#docCanvas')[0];
var cxt = $docCanvas.getContext('2d');
var canvasWidth;
var canvasHeight;
var imageObj = new Image();
var degreesToRotate = 0;
var imageScaledWidth;
var imageScaledHeight;
var canvasState = new CanvasState($docCanvas);


function init(imageSrc) {
    imageObj.onload = function () {
        $docCanvas.width = canvasWidth = imageObj.width;
        $docCanvas.height = canvasHeight = imageObj.height;
        imageScaledHeight = imageObj.height;
        imageScaledWidth = imageObj.width;

        cxt.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    };
    canvasState.addShape(new Shape(40, 40, 150, 50)); //default is grey
    imageObj.src = imageSrc;
}

$('#zoomIn').click(function () {
    scale = 1.25;
    resizeImage(scale);
});

$('#zoomOut').click(function () {
    scale = 0.8;
    resizeImage(scale);
});

$('#rotate').click(function () {
    degreesToRotate += 90;
    rotateImage(degreesToRotate);
});

function resizeImage(scale) {
    var heightRemainder = 0;
    var widthRemainder = 0;
    cxt.clearRect(0, 0, $docCanvas.width, $docCanvas.height);

    cxt.save();
    canvasState.valid = false;
    imageScaledWidth = imageScaledWidth * scale;
    imageScaledHeight = imageScaledHeight * scale;
    if (imageScaledWidth % 1 !== 0) {
        widthRemainder = imageScaledWidth % 1;
        imageScaledWidth = Math.round(imageScaledWidth);
    }

    if (imageScaledHeight % 1 !== 0) {
        heightRemainder = imageScaledHeight % 1;
        imageScaledHeight = Math.round(imageScaledHeight);
    }

    $docCanvas.width = imageScaledWidth;
    $docCanvas.height = imageScaledHeight;
    $.each(canvasState.shapes, function () {
        var shape = this;
        shape.resize(scale, widthRemainder, heightRemainder);
    });

    canvasState.draw(0, 0);


    cxt.restore();
}

function rotateImage(angle) {
    cxt.clearRect(0, 0, $docCanvas.width, $docCanvas.height);
    cxt.save();
    var centerWidth = imageScaledWidth / 2;
    var centerHeight = imageScaledHeight / 2;
    //move context to the center of the image
    cxt.translate(centerWidth, centerHeight);
    canvasState.valid = false;

    //rotate around the center of the image
    //the canvas rotate() method takes in an angle in radians.
    cxt.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);

    $.each(canvasState.shapes, function () {
        var shape = this;
        shape.rotate(angle);
    });

    canvasState.draw(-centerWidth, -centerHeight);

    cxt.restore();
}

function CanvasState(canvas) {
    // **** First some setup! **** 

    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.width = canvas.width;
    this.height = canvas.height;
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // This complicates things a little but but fixes mouse co-ordinate problems
    // when there's a border or padding. See getMouse for more detail
    var stylePaddingLeft, stylePaddingTop, styleBorderLeft, styleBorderTop;
    if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
        this.stylePaddingLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingLeft'], 10) || 0;
        this.stylePaddingTop = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingTop'], 10) || 0;
        this.styleBorderLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderLeftWidth'], 10) || 0;
        this.styleBorderTop = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderTopWidth'], 10) || 0;
    }

    // Some pages have fixed-position bars (like the stumbleupon bar) at the top or left of the page
    // They will mess up mouse coordinates and this fixes that
    var html = document.body.parentNode;
    this.htmlTop = html.offsetTop;
    this.htmlLeft = html.offsetLeft;

    // **** Keep track of state! ****

    this.valid = false; // when set to false, the canvas will redraw everything
    this.shapes = []; // the collection of things to be drawn
    this.dragging = false; // Keep track of when we are dragging

    // the current selected object. In the future we could turn this into an array for multiple selection
    this.selection = null;
    this.dragoffx = 0; // See mousedown and mousemove events for explanation
    this.dragoffy = 0;

    // **** Then events! ****

    // This is an example of a closure!
    // Right here "this" means the CanvasState. But we are making events on the Canvas itself,
    // and when the events are fired on the canvas the variable "this" is going to mean the canvas!
    // Since we still want to use this particular CanvasState in the events we have to save a reference to it.
    // This is our reference!
    var myState = this;

    //fixes a problem where double clicking causes text to get selected on the canvas
    canvas.addEventListener('selectstart', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }, false);

    // Up, down, and move are for dragging
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
        var mx = mouse.x;
        var my = mouse.y;
        var shapes = myState.shapes;
        var l = shapes.length;
        for (var i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (shapes[i].contains(mx, my)) {
                var mySel = shapes[i];
                // Keep track of where in the object we clicked
                // so we can move it smoothly (see mousemove)
                myState.dragoffx = mx - mySel.x;
                myState.dragoffy = my - mySel.y;
                myState.dragging = true;
                myState.selection = mySel;
                myState.valid = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        // havent returned means we have failed to select anything.
        // If there was an object selected, we deselect it
        if (myState.selection) {
            myState.selection = null;
            myState.valid = false; // Need to clear the old selection border
        }
    }, true);

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (myState.dragging) {
            var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
            // We don't want to drag the object by its top-left corner, we want to drag     it
            // from where we clicked. Thats why we saved the offset and use it here
            myState.selection.x = mouse.x - myState.dragoffx;
            myState.selection.y = mouse.y - myState.dragoffy;
            myState.valid = false; // Something's dragging so we must redraw
        }
    }, true);

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        myState.dragging = false;
    }, true);

    // double click for making new shapes
    //canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', function (e) {
    //  var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
    //  myState.addShape(new Shape(mouse.x - 10, mouse.y - 10, 20, 20, 'rgba(0,255,0,.6)'));
    //}, true);

    // **** Options! ****

    this.selectionColor = '#CC0000';
    this.selectionWidth = 2;
    this.interval = 30;
    setInterval(function () {
        myState.draw(0, 0);
    }, myState.interval);
}

CanvasState.prototype.addShape = function (shape) {
    this.shapes.push(shape);
    this.valid = false;
};

CanvasState.prototype.clear = function () {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
};

// While draw is called as often as the INTERVAL variable demands,
// It only ever does something if the canvas gets invalidated by our code
CanvasState.prototype.draw = function (centerWidth, centerHeight) {
    // if our state is invalid, redraw and validate!
    if (!this.valid) {
        var ctx = this.ctx;
        var shapes = this.shapes;
        this.clear();

        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, centerWidth, centerHeight, imageScaledWidth,     imageScaledHeight);

        // ** Add stuff you want drawn in the background all the time here **

        // draw all shapes
        var l = shapes.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var shape = shapes[i];
            // We can skip the drawing of elements that have moved off the screen:
            if (shape.x > imageScaledWidth || shape.y > imageScaledHeight || shape.x +     shape.w < 0 || shape.y + shape.h < 0) continue;
            shapes[i].draw(ctx);
        }

        // draw selection
        // right now this is just a stroke along the edge of the selected Shape
        if (this.selection !== null) {
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.selectionColor;
            ctx.lineWidth = this.selectionWidth;
            var mySel = this.selection;
            ctx.strokeRect(mySel.x, mySel.y, mySel.w, mySel.h);
        }

        // ** Add stuff you want drawn on top all the time here **

        this.valid = true;
    }
};


// Creates an object with x and y defined, set to the mouse position relative to the state's canvas
// If you wanna be super-correct this can be tricky, we have to worry about padding and borders
CanvasState.prototype.getMouse = function (e) {
    var element = this.canvas,
    offsetX = 0,
    offsetY = 0,
    mx, my;

    // Compute the total offset
    if (element.offsetParent !== undefined) {
        do {
            offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
            offsetY += element.offsetTop;
        } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
    }

    // Add padding and border style widths to offset
    // Also add the <html> offsets in case there's a position:fixed bar
    offsetX += this.stylePaddingLeft + this.styleBorderLeft + this.htmlLeft;
    offsetY += this.stylePaddingTop + this.styleBorderTop + this.htmlTop;

    mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
    my = e.pageY - offsetY;

    // We return a simple javascript object (a hash) with x and y defined
    return {
        x: mx,
        y: my
    };
};

// Constructor for Shape objects to hold data for all drawn objects.
// For now they will just be defined as rectangles.
function Shape(x, y, w, h, fill) {
    // This is a very simple and unsafe constructor. 
    // All we're doing is checking if the values exist.
    // "x || 0" just means "if there is a value for x, use that. Otherwise use 0."
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
    this.w = w || 1;
    this.h = h || 1;
    this.fill = fill || '#000000';
}

// Draws this shape to a given context
Shape.prototype.draw = function (ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
};

// Determine if a point is inside the shape's bounds
Shape.prototype.contains = function (mx, my) {
    // All we have to do is make sure the Mouse X,Y fall in the area between
    // the shape's X and (X + Height) and its Y and (Y + Height)
    return (this.x <= mx) && (this.x + this.w >= mx) && (this.y <= my) && (this.y + this.h >= my);
};


Shape.prototype.resize = function (scale, widthRemainder, heightRemainder) {
    if (widthRemainder > 4) {
        this.x = this.x * scale + widthRemainder;
    } else {
        this.x = this.x * scale - widthRemainder;
    }
    if (heightRemainder > 4) {
        this.y = this.y * scale + heightRemainder;
    } else {
        this.y = this.y * scale - heightRemainder;
    }
    this.h = this.h * scale;
    this.w = this.w * scale;
};

Shape.prototype.rotate = function (angle) {
    var temp;
    if (angle == 90 || angle == 270) {
        temp = this.w;
        this.w = this.h;
        this.h = temp;
    }
};
```

Comment: I am not familliar with this but I think css3 and html5 do this now without need to do javascript. Maybe this could be a good option? (http://www.w3schools.com/css3/)

Comment: Please copy some of your code into your question. Stack Overflow prefers that the majority of the question and answer can be viewed on their site in the case that any links become broken. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two canvases for this - that will save you a lot of head-ache.

When you translate a canvas the whole coordinate system is translated as well. This affect what you draw next (the squares on top of the canvas).

One option, using the same canvas, is to counter-calculate the positions. This is not so hard when just doing translate and scale, but is a bit more complicated when you do a rotate (doable but in comes the head-ache part).

The easier solution is to create two canvases stacked on top of each other. Do this by creating a parent element with position `relative` and put the two canvases inside using position absolute (there are other ways but to keep it simple for now).

Now you can rotate and draw the image in the bottom canvas and draw the rectangles, tracking moves etc. on the upper canvas.

However, there is one drawback and that is if you use those squares to perform any operation on the image where they resides. Then you are back to calculate counter points.

To calculate the points you need to track all translations in an accumulative fashion. Assuming this is done you can use some code like (from my [easyCanvas project](http://easycanvasjs.com/)):

```
function calcCoords(x, y) {

    var r = me.canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), cx, cy, ang, l;

    x = (x - r.left - me.deltaX) / zoomX;
    y = (y - r.top - me.deltaY) / zoomY;

    if (rotation !== 0) {

        cx = me.width * me.pivotX / zoomX;
        cy = me.height * me.pivotY / zoomY;

        ang = (getAngle(cx, cy, x, y) - rotation) * deg2rad;
        l = getDist(cx, cy, x, y);

        x = cx + l  * Math.cos(ang);
        y = cy + l  * Math.sin(ang);

    }

    return [x, y];
}

function getAngle(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

    var ang = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * rad2deg;
    if (ang < 0) ang += 360;

    return ang;
}
```

You can use this by calling:

```
var newCoords = calcCoord(originalX, originalY);
var newX = newCoords[0];
var newY = newCoords[1];
```

`zoomX/Y` is current scale.
`pivotX/Y` is current pivot (typically 0.5)
`width/height` is of canvas
`rotation` is accumulated angle in degrees

To see this in action you can go to this sample from the link above:
http://abdiassoftware.com/easycanvas/samples/sample_basicpaintext.html

(for best result use Chrome).

Comment: Even though I set the top canvas' width and height to be the same as the bottom one, it doesn't seem to be the same dimensions. When I try to draw the square doesn't clear when I drag over the bottom canvas. When I rotate the bottom canvas the top canvas doesn't rotate with it either.

Answer (score 0):

If you use or can use CSS3, it has a built in function to rotate elements

```
div
{
    transform:rotate(30deg);
}
```

It also have a scale function so you could rescale your element to "zoom" in and out
You could also use this tutorial to help you http://www.w3schools.com/css3/

Comment: That does get the shapes to stay in the same position, but now the squares cannot be moved if the div is not at 0 degrees of rotation.